# App Engine JDO DataNucleus Cursor is null when using projection queries

Tags: google-app-engine, cursor, jdo, datanucleus

I want to use DataNucleus JDO with Google App Engine and with projection queries.  But when I execute the query I get expected results, but the cursor is null.  Using DataNucleus 3.1.3.  I am using DataNucleus TypeSafe queries.

If I execute the same query without using projection queries, I get expected results as well as a valid not-null cursor.  Is this DataNucleus bug or App Engine does not return cursor for projection queries?

Code using projection queries (Cursor is null):

```
    List<Object[]> accountFieldsList = null;
    TypesafeQuery<Account> tq = getTQ(); // get this query
    accountFieldsList = tq.executeResultList(true, cand.accountNumber, cand.lastName, cand.firstName);

    Cursor cursorNew = JDOCursorHelper.getCursor(accountFieldsList);
    cursorStrNew = cursorNew.toWebSafeString(); <--THIS IS NULL
```

Code WITHOUT using projection queries (Cursor is NOT null):

```
    List<Account> results = tq.executeList();
    Cursor cursorNew = JDOCursorHelper.getCursor(results);
    cursorStrNew = cursorNew.toWebSafeString(); <--THIS IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: thought of looking in the log?

Comment: FWIW. clearly this "Cursor" is nothing to do with JDO, or DataNucleus, but is only something that Google provides.

Comment: Checked logs, but they don't give any clue.  Looks like app engine doesn't support cursor with projection queries.

Comment: If that's the case, CoolDude, that seems to be purely undocumented....